# Data and Database Storage in Different Regions of AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-efs

I am working on a medical product that is accessible in different regions of the word and collect the data from the patients, as per distribution law i cant take the patients data, history or record to another country. The basic requirement is that US sites should have all related data stored in US data centers (such as the current US east data center) and EU based sites should have all data in EU based data centers (such as AWS Ireland or Frankfurt).

How this is most efficiently done should be analysed - run two completely different stacks? Or should there just be a database and EFS system in place in these different locations?

Comment: This is the same problem I am facing. Did you manage to find a good solution to your query Sheikh?

Comment: I initiated multiple mysql instances in different region under same VPC, and the sensitive data is moved to regional databases, for EFS i am using JSON Blobs in mysql as my database have no major hits at the moment

Answer (score 3):

You will want to host separate instances of your application stack in each region, including data stores and services that access them. There are two main reasons:

- To provide good performance for your customers, your services need low-latency access to the data stores. While you could access an S3 bucket or DynamoDB table from another region than the one it is hosted in, you will experience higher latencies when doing so
- To really deliver the data sovreignity your customers are asking for, you should keep the data from ever leaving the region where they want the data stored

One approach to explore would be modeling your entire service as a CloudFormation template, with parameters to control the differences between regions. That makes it much easier to deploy the same infrastructure to multiple regions.

Answer (score 0):

We are working on the Same type of application requirement.

so you can keep your application stacks separate for each region. you can get region value in each application deployed in cloud.

Based on region value locate the S3 bucket and database. Before going for EFS be sure on EFS implementation.

Let me know if you have any specific requirement of AWS Resources in your Application Development.

Comment: is it good to make copies of application, also we are currently using efs

Comment: We are not using EFS. But region restricted applications we do not have other choice. Plan  your CI and CD accordingly.

Comment: what about cloud Front ? is there any way we can use that and save data on different distribution ?

Comment: As per aws https://aws.amazon.com/compliance/hipaa-compliance/ cloudfront not under compliance. How do you use cloudfront to serve static content or storing objects to s3.